# Access static property of protocol extension

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-extensions

I'm trying to build a protocol exposing a static property, then use that static property in an extension of that protocol, but it seems to work only if I define this static property in the protocol extension as well.
Basically the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
protocol NibInstantiable: class {
    static var bundle: Bundle? { get }
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

extension NibInstantiable where Self: UIViewController {
//    static var nibName: String {
//        return ""
//    }

    static func instantiate() -> Self {
        return Self(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: Self.bundle ?? Bundle.main)
    }
}
```

This used to work basically as-is in Swift 2, but it's no longer the case in Swift 3. I can get it to work by uncommenting the `nibName` property in the protocol extension, but that would suppress compiler warnings if I forget to define this property in classes that implement this protocol.

Any idea what I'm missing ?
Thanks !

EDIT: For reference, here is a Swift 2.3 version of that code that compiles and works without any issue:

```
protocol Instantiable {
    static var bundle: NSBundle? { get }
    static func instantiate() -> Self
}
extension Instantiable {
    static var bundle: NSBundle? {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle()
    }
}
// MARK: With Nib
protocol NibInstantiable: Instantiable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

extension NibInstantiable where Self: UIViewController {
    static func instantiate() -> Self {
        return Self(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: Self.bundle ?? NSBundle.mainBundle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure static variable `bundle` has `String` type? Try to add actual code, it would help us to help you with your problems. Any change may introduce additional bugs.

Comment: My bad, the type is `Bundle?` (fixed now). Actually there's no more to it than the snippet here.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me – the compiler thinks there's a conflict between `UIViewController`'s `nibName` instance property and your static `nibName` property requirement. See [this related bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2992) – a simple solution would just be to rename your static `nibName` requirement.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Dunno why the other answer was deleted, but if you want to convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @axelcdv Sure thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me (see the related bug report [SR-2992](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2992)) – the compiler thinks that there's a conflict between `UIViewController`'s [`nibName`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname) instance property and your `NibInstantiable` protocol's `nibName` static property requirement. A simpler reproducible example would be:

```
protocol Foo {
    static var bar : String { get }
}

class Bar {
    var bar = "" // commenting out this line allows the code to compile
}

extension Foo where Self : Bar {
    static func qux() {
        print(bar) // compiler error: Instance member 'bar' cannot be used on type 'Self'
    }
}
```

A simple workaround would be to just rename your protocol's `nibName` static property requirement.