# Swift - Generic that subclasses and conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I basically have this protocol

```
  protocol ReusableView {
     static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
  }
```

and this generic class

```
  class ListController<Item: Equatable, Cell: UITableViewCell>: UIViewController where Cell: ReusableView {

      private var items: [Item]

      init(items: [Item]) {
         self.items = items
         super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
         print(Cell.reuseIdentifier)
      }
  }
```

When I try to print the reuseIdentifier, I get this compiler error

> Instance member 'reuseIdentifier' cannot be used on type 'Cell'

I should be able to access the property since the Cell Object conforms to the ReusableView protocol.

I don't know what the problem is. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [Access static property of protocol extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41329940/2976878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is occurring because `Cell` must inherit from `UITableViewCell` which already defines an instance variable `reuseIdentifier`. Simply changing the name of `reuseIdentifier` to `reusableViewIdentifier` or something will cause the error to go away.